# Instagram Realtime API auto unsubscribing high volume tags

Tags: php, symfony, instagram, instagram-api

I read over the instagram developer docs that instagram unsubscribes tags if we are not acknowledge the POST within a 2 second timeout.

How do I make sure, my code responds in 2 seconds?How do I check when the unsubscription happening?

Here is my code. I am using php.Please advise

```
    if ($challenge) {
        echo $challenge;
        exit ();
    } else {


        $myString = file_get_contents ( 'php://input' );
        $jsonArray = json_decode ( $myString );

        foreach ( $jsonArray as $value ) {

            $hashtag = $value->object_id;

            $firstApi = 1;

                exec ( "php getInstagramData.php $hashtag ");

        }
    }
```